# Speeding up a MySQL insert select into with 10 millions records

Tags: mysql, database, indexing, insert

I have a few table storing daily orders, customers and salespersons. Yet the schema was not well design as columns have inappropriate data value and type, missing index and partition etc. I re-designed a new schema and populate the new tables with the wrecked tables. I am now stuck on populating the daily orders table (with around 10M records).

Attached data definition and the SQL script to populate the table.

**TABLE DEFINITION**

```
 CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `testing`.`Orders` (
   `order_ID` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `ord_id` BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `create_time` DATETIME NOT NULL,
  `create_date` DATE NOT NULL,
  `cust_id` MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `cust_mob` BIGINT UNSIGNED NULL,
  `sales_id` MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED NULL,
  `sales_mob` BIGINT UNSIGNED NULL,
  `sales_flag` TINYINT UNSIGNED NULL,
  `comm_flag` TINYINT UNSIGNED NULL,
  `extraprice` TINYINT UNSIGNED NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`order_ID`),
  INDEX `Date_cust_id` (`create_date` ASC, `cust_id` ASC),
  INDEX `Date_cust_mob` (`create_date` ASC, `cust_mob` ASC),
  INDEX `Date_dri_id` (`create_date` ASC, `sales_id` ASC),
  INDEX `Date_dri_mob` (`create_date` ASC, `sales_mob` ASC),
  INDEX `Date_cust` (`create_date` ASC, `cust_id` ASC, `cstu_mob` ASC),
  INDEX `Date_dri` (`create_date` ASC, `sales_id` ASC, `sales_mob` ASC),
  INDEX `cust` (`cust_id` ASC, `cust_mob` ASC),
  INDEX `dri` (`sales_id` ASC, `sales_mob` ASC),
  UNIQUE INDEX `ord_id_UNIQUE` (`ord_id` ASC)
  )
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8;
```

This script is to populate the table, involving two left join tables: Pag table with 6xx K record and dri table with 3x k record.

```
SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES=0;
SET SQL_MODE='';

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS testing.populate_ord1;
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE testing.populate_ord1()
BEGIN
    PREPARE stmt 
       FROM "
            INSERT INTO testing.Orders 
            SELECT 
            1
            ,ord_id
            ,CASE WHEN TRIM(create_time) ='NULL' THEN NULL ELSE STR_TO_DATE(substring(create_time,1,19), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s') END AS create_time
            ,CASE WHEN TRIM(create_time) ='NULL' THEN NULL ELSE DATE(STR_TO_DATE(substring(create_time,1,19), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s')) END AS create_date
            ,CASE WHEN TRIM(ord.cust_id) = 'NULL' THEN NULL else pag.cust_id END as cust_id
            ,CASE WHEN TRIM(ord.mob) = 'NULL' THEN NULL else pag.cust_mob END as cust_mob
            ,CASE WHEN TRIM(ord.sales_id) = 'NULL' THEN NULL else dri.sales_id END as sales_id
            ,CASE WHEN TRIM(ord.mob1) = 'NULL' THEN NULL else dri.sales_mob END as sales_mob
            ,CASE WHEN TRIM(sales_flag) ='NULL' THEN NULL ELSE CONVERT(TRIM(sales_flag),UNSIGNED INTEGER) end  AS sales_flag
            ,CASE WHEN TRIM(comm_flag) ='NULL' THEN NULL ELSE  CONVERT(TRIM(comm_flag),UNSIGNED INTEGER)  end AS comm_flag
            ,CASE WHEN TRIM(extraprice) ='NULL' THEN NULL ELSE  CONVERT(TRIM(extraprice),UNSIGNED INTEGER) end AS extraprice

            FROM testing.ord_table ord
                LEFT JOIN
                (SELECT cust_id,customer_id,cust_mob FROM testing.Passenger) pag
                ON TRIM(ord.customer_id) = TRIM(pag.pag_id)
                AND TRIM(ord.mob) = TRIM(pag.passenger_mob)
                LEFT JOIN
                (SELECT sales_id,salesperson_id,sales_mob FROM testing.sales) dri
                ON TRIM(ord.salesperson_id) = TRIM(dri.sales_id)
                AND TRIM(ord.mob1) = TRIM(dri.sales_mob)
            WHERE ord_id  != 'NULL' AND create_time IS NOT NULL AND create_time != 'NULL' AND YEAR(create_time) = ? AND MONTH(create_time) = ? AND DAY(create_time) = ?
            GROUP BY ord_id
            ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE  ord_id = ord_id
            ;

            ";


    SET @y = 2014, @m = 9, @d = 1;

    WHILE @y<= 2014 DO
        WHILE @m<= 12 DO
            SET @d = 1;
            WHILE @d<= 31 DO
                EXECUTE stmt USING @y, @m, @d;
                SET @d = @d + 1;
            END WHILE;
            SET @m = @m + 1;
        END WHILE;
        SET @y = @y + 1;
        SET @m = 1;
    END WHILE;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;


END$$
DELIMITER ;

set autocommit=0;
call testing.populate_ord1();
COMMIT;
```

I have failed to populate any record to the table. Sometimes it raises lock wait timeout error or data type error or simply takes too long time (2 days)  I suspect it is even doing any job.

I searched the web a bit and have added the following settings to my.cnf.

```
innodb_autoinc_lock_mode = 2
innodb_lock_wait_time_out = 150
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit =2 
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 14G
```

Would anyone advise on how I could accomplish the same task efficiently? The code above run without any syntax error. And in case if there is any naming confusion, please let me know if that's critical to get clarified as I am slightly tweaked those variable tables.

Comment: Do you actually have the text string `"NULL"` in some columns?  That is _not_ the same as `NULL`, and `NULL` cannot be tested with `=`.

Comment: Is this a one-time action or it will be a kind of scheduled job?

Comment: yes 'NULL' exists as column value & it is a one time task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start by performing

```
UPDATE ... SET
    comm_flag  = TRIM(comm_flag),
    sales_flag = TRIM(sales_flag),
    ...
```

That will speed up the subsequent queries *some*, and simplify them.

Then avoid using `LEFT JOIN ( SELECT ... FROM x WHERE ... )`.  Instead, see if you can turn that into `LEFT JOIN x ON ... WHERE ...`.  That is likely to help.

It is usually a bad idea to split a DATE and TIME into two columns.  Or do you have a good argument for such?  Let's see the queries that touch that pair of columns.

There is no need for `STR_TO_DATE()` if the string is already a properly formatted `DATE` or `DATETIME`.  That is, a string works just fine.

Once the `TRIM` is out of the way, `CONVERT(TRIM(comm_flag),UNSIGNED INTEGER)` can be simply `comm_flag`.

Don't loop through things a day at a time -- the way you have it structured, it will be doing a full table scan!  About 1000 times !!  (This is likely to be the biggest performance issue.)

Comment: Thanks I would try...I was not splitting the date & time into two columns. I add an extra date column just because very often we will query on date data.